# SELECT name and rowcount?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I've bloody well done this before, but I plumb forget how.

I have a table of Schools, each with an ID and name.

I have another table of Students, each with a school_id foreign key.

I want to write a query that'll return a list of schools and the count of their students I have on record; something like this:

```
School1 - 319
School2 - 166
School3 - 120
```

Bonus if it can be done elegantly in Rails without resorting to raw SQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can just do:

```
SELECT s.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM schools s
INNER JOIN students ss ON ss.schoolID = s.id
GROUP BY s.ID
```

(about the rails part i can't help you, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

No rails points for me:

```
SELECT
school_name, count(*)

FROM
schools

LEFT JOIN
students
USING(school_id)

GROUP BY
school_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT s.schoolName, COUNT(st.id) 
FROM Schools s
JOIN Students st
  ON st.school_id = s.school_id
GROUP BY s.school_id
```